# ObjectiveC - how to use NSUserNotification identifier property

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, notifications, nsusernotification, nsusernotificationcenter

According to the apple docs https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsusernotification/1416410-identifier

NSUserNotification has a property called identifier which is suppose to replace notifications when the identifier is the same as another notification.

When I was testing this feature out however it seems that the notification is not really replaced, just not sent.

How would I achieve the effect where only one type of notification is present in the notification center but the latest one called is updated to the top?

**Sending notification A + notification B + notification A with a 1 minute delay**

**This is what is being shown on the mac notification center**

***Without identifier***

```
NotificationA (now) 
NotificationB (1 minute ago) 
NotificationA (2 minute ago)
```

***With identifier***

```
NotificationB (1 minute ago) 
NotificationA (2 minute ago)
```

Notice how Notification A (2nd time) is not called due to the identifier being present

***Desired effect***

```
NotificationA (now) 
NotificationB (1 minute ago)
```

In this situation Notification A is sent again and the previous Notification A is gone

Comment: We faced a similar problem in Chrome and we ended up deleting the notification and re-adding it again. The code is not yet enabled by default but you can try it out by toggling some flags. Happy to provide more info if that helps. https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/notifications/notification_platform_bridge_mac.mm?rcl=0&l=142

Comment: That does, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete an existing `notification` using the `NSNotificationCenter`s `removeDeliveredNotification:` method. 
Just remove and re-add your notification.

**Objective-C**

```
[[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter] removeDeliveredNotification:userNotification];
[[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter] deliverNotification:userNotification];
```

**Swift**

```
NSUserNotificationCenter.default.removeDeliveredNotification(userNotification)
NSUserNotificationCenter.default.deliver(userNotification)
```

I successfully used this technique to show notifications without polluting the notification center.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the order should be reversed: first removing previous notification and then delivering new.

Comment: You're right, in this example we should first remove the old one. I used this code where I wanted to show a notification, but didn't want it to appear in Notification Center